Trying to fetch all the Data of a collection but keep getting "No Setter For Fields"
I'm facing an issue with mapping data from Firestore to Java objects in my Spring Boot application. Specifically, when retrieving data from Firestore and mapping it to my Java class, most fields are being set as null except for "Bioma" and "Grupo". Other fields like "Categoria de Ameaça", "Estados de Ocorrência", etc., are null even though the Firestore data has valid values for these fields.
This is the JSON file that I currently uploading to the Firestore Database:
{
        "Categoria de Ameaça": "Vulnerável (VU)",
        "Espécie exclusiva do Brasil": "Sim",
        "Estados de Ocorrência": "PR",
        "Principais Ameaças": "Perda de Habitat/Degradação (Induzida por Humanos)",
        "Sigla Categoria de Ameaça": "VU",
        "Plano de Ação Nacional para Conservação (PAN)": "Sim",
        "Família": "Salicaceae",
        "Bioma": "Mata Atlântica",
        "Nível de Proteção na Estratégia Nacional": "2",
        "Espécie (Simplificado)": "Abatia angeliana",
        "Nome Comum": "-",
        "Ordenamento Pesqueiro ": "Não",
        "Grupo": "Angiospermas",
        "Fauna/Flora": "Flora",
        "Presença em Áreas Protegidas": "Sim"
    },
    {
        "Categoria de Ameaça": "Em Perigo (EN)",
        "Espécie exclusiva do Brasil": "Não",
        "Estados de Ocorrência": "BA; ES; MG; PR; RJ; RS; SC; SP",
        "Principais Ameaças": "Agropecuária; Assentamento Humano:cidades; Extracao Direta:Caça/Pesca; Extracao Florestal",
        "Sigla Categoria de Ameaça": "EN",
        "Plano de Ação Nacional para Conservação (PAN)": "Não",
        "Família": "Cracidae",
        "Bioma": "Cerrado; Mata Atlântica",
        "Nível de Proteção na Estratégia Nacional": "4",
        "Espécie (Simplificado)": "Aburria jacutinga",
        "Nome Comum": "Jacutinga",
        "Ordenamento Pesqueiro ": "Não",
        "Grupo": "Aves",
        "Fauna/Flora": "Fauna",
        "Presença em Áreas Protegidas": "Sim"
    },
    {
        "Categoria de Ameaça": "Criticamente em Perigo (CR)",
        "Espécie exclusiva do Brasil": "Sim",
        "Estados de Ocorrência": "RJ",
        "Principais Ameaças": "Assentamentos Humanos: Cidades",
        "Sigla Categoria de Ameaça": "CR",
        "Plano de Ação Nacional para Conservação (PAN)": "Sim",
        "Família": "Malvaceae",
        "Bioma": "Mata Atlântica",
        "Nível de Proteção na Estratégia Nacional": "2",
        "Espécie (Simplificado)": "Abutilon anodoides",
        "Nome Comum": "-",
        "Ordenamento Pesqueiro ": "Não",
        "Grupo": "Angiospermas",
        "Fauna/Flora": "Flora",
        "Presença em Áreas Protegidas": "Sim"
    }

And this is how my Species class is modeled on Spring,I already double-check every field to make sure that they match:
package com.example.Rest.FireBase.Model;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import lombok.*;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;


@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Species {
    @SerializedName("Categoria de Ameaça")
    private String CategoriaDeAmeaca;

    @SerializedName("\n" +
            "Espécie (Simplificado)")
    private String EspecieExclusivaDoBrasil;

    @SerializedName("Estados de Ocorrência")
    private String EstadosDeOcorrencia;

    @SerializedName("Principais Ameaças")
    private String PrincipaisAmeacas;

    @SerializedName("Sigla Categoria de Ameaça")
    private String SiglaCategoriaDeAmeaca;

    @SerializedName("Plano de Ação Nacional para Conservação (PAN)")
    private String PlanoDeAcaoNacionalParaConservacao;

    @SerializedName("Família")
    private String Familia;

    @SerializedName("Bioma")
    private String Bioma;

    @SerializedName("Nível de Proteção na Estratégia Nacional")
    private String NivelDeProtecaoNaEstrategiaNacional;

    @SerializedName("Espécie (Simplificado)")
    private String EspecieSimplificado;

    @SerializedName("Nome Comum")
    private String NomeComum;

    @SerializedName("Ordenamento Pesqueiro ")
    private String OrdenamentoPesqueiro;

    @SerializedName("Grupo")
    private String Grupo;

    @SerializedName("Fauna/Flora")  
    private String FaunaFlora;

    @SerializedName("Presença em Áreas Protegidas")
    private String PresencaEmAreasProtegidas;
}

This is my service from retrieve all the species in the collection
  public List<Species> getAllSpecies () throws  ExecutionException,InterruptedException {
        Firestore firestore = FirestoreClient.getFirestore();
       CollectionReference collection = firestore.collection("bichos");
       ApiFuture<QuerySnapshot> querySnapshot = collection.get();
       List<Species> speciesList = new ArrayList<>();
       for (DocumentSnapshot document : querySnapshot.get().getDocuments()) {
           Species species = document.toObject(Species.class);
           speciesList.add(species);
       }
        return speciesList;
   }

My controller for the service:
 @GetMapping("/all")
    public List<Species> getAllSpecies() {
        try {
            return speciesService.getAllSpecies();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

and lastly the output that I get:
[Rest-FireBase] [nio-8080-exec-1] c.g.cloud.firestore.CustomClassMapper    : No setter/field for Família found on class com.example.Rest.FireBase.Model.Species
2024-05-15T00:10:49.030-03:00  WARN 32736 --- [Rest-FireBase] [nio-8080-exec-1] c.g.cloud.firestore.CustomClassMapper    : No setter/field for Bioma found on class com.example.Rest.FireBase.Model.Species (fields/setters are case sensitive!)
2024-05-15T00:10:49.030-03:00  WARN 32736 --- [Rest-FireBase] [nio-8080-exec-1] c.g.cloud.firestore.CustomClassMapper    : No setter/field for Nível de Proteção na Estratégia Nacional found on class com.example.Rest.FireBase.Model.Species
2024-05-15T00:10:49.030-03:00  WARN 32736 --- [Rest-FireBase] [nio-8080-exec-1] c.g.cloud.firestore.CustomClassMapper    : No setter/field for Espécie (Simplificado) found on class com.example.Rest.FireBase.Model.Species
2024-05-15T00:10:49.030-03:00  WARN 32736 --- [Rest-FireBase] [nio-8080-exec-1] c.g.cloud.firestore.CustomClassMapper    : No setter/field for Nome Comum found on class com.example.Rest.FireBase.Model.Species
2024-05-15T00:10:49.030-03:00  WARN 32736 --- [Rest-FireBase] [nio-8080-exec-1] c.g.cloud.firestore.CustomClassMapper    : No setter/field for Ordenamento Pesqueiro  found on class com.example.Rest.FireBase.Model.Species

I tried changing names,fiels and eving using Gson to convert,In the Firestore all the documents are saved in the collection but my output is always an json array with null objects

it looks a bit strange to me, that you have @SerializedName("Espécie (Simplificado)") twice in your class (once with a leading \n , which seems even stranger to me..).
It might be a good idea to clean this up and afterwards remove the problematic fields, adding them until problem occurs again and examine then.
Are your special characters allowed at all?

Sorry,I ended up leaving like this when copying and pasting to the question. But even without duplicate fields the error persists.

A clarification, are you getting those nulls in the resulting response (in the json)? Or in Species instances?

did you try without "foreign" characters? Or tried to escape them?

@SerializedName is the annotation for Gson but you get a warning from the Firebase method DocumentSnapshot.toObject().
Solution
For all fields where the name of the Java field differs from Firebase field name you should add Firebase annotation as well. Like this:
@SerializedName("Categoria de Ameaça")
@PropertyName("Categoria de Ameaça")
private String CategoriaDeAmeaca;


Thank you,It worked I didn't think that I didn't notice the difference
